# Click on Class names in VBA - No Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I am into Project Management with no knowledge of IT / Coding.
I am trying to do web automation.
It will have to click on certain links, submit a form and then hit save.
However I am not able to click on the first link as well. 
this is my code as of now.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ie As Object
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim form As Variant, button As Variant

Sheet1.Range("B6").Value = Application.UserName

'Open Internet Explorer

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


ie.navigate "https://www.link.com/"

ie.Visible = True

While ie.Busy

DoEvents

Wend

Set html = ie.document

html.getElementsByClassID("p2205").Click


End Sub
```

Below is the code.
I want to click on Company Name.

Website Code

[image]

I have tried the web and YouTube videos as well but I guess I don't know the language or the logic behind coding. Hence I am not able to get through.

Comment: `p2527` looks like an `ID`, not a `class` - so you probably want `getElementByID` instead.

Comment: You should look at PowerAutomate Desktop.  It's free to Windows 10 users.

Comment: @braX sorry for the confusion. but its not the line highlighted. the 3rd line from the bottom which has an inner text "Company Name". that is what i want to click

Comment: @Skin this will be used in a company environment. Where I am limited to VBA only. cant extend to anything else. :|

Comment: If you want a class, then use `getElementsByClassName` as there is no such thing as `getElementsByClassID` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getelementsbyclassname

Comment: @braX thank you for the link. this is very confusing for me :/
I'll check the relevant posts and try.

I've also tried using "getElementsByClassName", it still does not work.

I tried "getElementByID" for ID = p2205, it still wont work.

I am pretty sure I am missing something important, which is messing the flow of the code.
not sure what exactly. i wish i could talk to someone about this xd

Answer (score 0):

Add reference to Microsoft Internet Controls then try

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     
    Dim ie As Object, html As HTMLDocument, e As HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim URL As String
    
    URL = "https://www.link.com/"
    
    Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
    ie.navigate URL
    ie.Visible = True
    
    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    
    Set html = ie.document
    For Each e In html.getElementsByClassName("dsh_sta_301")
       If InStr(e.onclick, "projectSelection") > 0 Then
           e.Click
       End If
    Next
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for showing interest in helping me.  
I initially got this error when i Run your code.  
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':  Automation Error  Unspecified Error  After some google search, I figured that I had to mention the wait cycle.  
I added the following to the code  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))  While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE'use "<> 4" if working in late binding, ie no reference to the ieframe library  DoEvents  Wend  Now, I get an error stating  Run-time error '462':  remote machine unavailable

Comment: @Munk add `Exit Sub` after `ie.Visible = True` and confirm IE working.